# Why use const in C#?

Tags: c#

What's the point of ever using `const`?

It is more restrictive than `static readonly`:

- across assemblies, changes to a `const`in a dependency won't be reflected in its consumers
- you can only use `const` for certain primitive types

with both these restrictions in mind, perhaps among others I am not aware of,  why ever use `const`?

Why not always use `static readonly` to maintain consistency of style?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190870/const-string-vs-static-readonly-string-in-c-sharp?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/static-readonly-vs-const).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have done a little research, and I'm aware of at least most of the most well-known differences. But from reading those, it now seems like const is less versatile and has no positives in its favor...

Comment: You'll find a decent explanation of when to use which [here](https://exceptionnotfound.net/const-vs-static-vs-readonly-in-c-sharp-applications/).

Comment: @candied_orange It still doesn't give any reason to actually use const over static readonly... it just describes what const stops you from doing

Comment: The point of all high level languages is what they stop you from doing.

Answer (score 8):

Things declared `const` are true compile-time constants, and thus may occur in constant-expressions. This means you can use them in the following contexts, where `static readonly` variables may not appear[1]:

- Values of other constants: `const int OTHER = N;`
- Explicit values of enum members: `enum Foo { Bar = N }`
- Default arguments: `void Fn(int i = N)`
- `case` labels: `case N:` and `goto case N;`
- Attribute values: `[Value(N)]`
- (rather irrelevant) array creation with initializers: `new int[N] { 1, 2, 3 }`

[1] https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#constant-expressions

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. Why is the array creation one "rather irrelevant" in your opinion?

Comment: Very good answer but the first bullet point is kind of irrelevant (+1 nonethelesss). If you use `static readonly` instead of `const`, you won't be trying to assign to any `const`s either.

Comment: Using the const in an array creation expression is meaningless because you can omit the explicit size and the compiler will implicitly size the array by the size of the initializer list.

Comment: @theonlygusti Pretty much what Avner said. I think you can write `new[MORE_THAN_THREE] { 1, 2, 3 }` and the additional elements are default-initialized, but I don't know when that use case ever comes up, except perhaps in a prime filter toy.

Comment: @SebastianRedl no, this doesn't compile (Error CS0847)

Comment: Then all it really does is ensure that you have the right number of initializers. Which might be a useful check to have sometimes. (Imagine the constant is defined by some library.)

Comment: Well I was imagining `char[] buffer = new char[BufferSize];` for example, then populating it later....